# Odd behaviour when in async await (maybe because of multiple requests)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, async-await

I have the following use-case, `FetchDataService` (injected as scoped), is fetching data from API using httpClient.
Then the service analyze the data and run `await SaveAsync` it to the database.
Everything till this point works great.
Then I added another service: `AddressEnrichmentService` (injected as scoped) that during the "analyze" phase is calling external service asyncly and bring more data.
This service is messing the entire app. I get random exceptions from the database handler (NHibernate) that is indicating some thread problems. I really can't put my finger on it. few different random exceptions... 
These exceptions are thrown when running `await SaveAsync`.  (I will add them in the end).

```
public async Task Fetch(string url, UserModel userModel ){
    string res = null;
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()){
       res = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
    }
    await databaseLogRepository.SaveAsync(new Log{Message = "The data is here..." + res});
    var profile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProfileModel >(res);

    profile.Data.Locations.ForEach(async x =>
    {
        var address = await addressEnrichmentService.EnrichAsync(x.StreetAddress + " " + x.Locality + " " + x.Country);
        userModel.Address = address;
        await databaseLogRepository.SaveAsync(new Log{Message = "enriched address"});
   });
}
```

The problematic service:

```
public class AddressEnrichmentService : IAddressEnrichmentService
{
        public async Task<AddressModel> EnrichAsync(string address)
        {
            string res = null;
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=__KEY__&address=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(address);
                    res = await client.GetStringAsync(url);// probably the problematic row
            }
             return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddressModel>(res);
        }
 }
```

Usage

```
UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
await fetchDataService.Fetch(url, userModel);
await userRepo.SaveAsync(userModel);
```

Again `addressEnrichmentService.EnrichAsync` is messing everything up.
How do I know `EnrichAsync` is messing it up?
if I convert `res = await client.GetStringAsync(url);` to `res = client.GetStringAsync(url).GetAwaiter().GetResult();` I dont get any error. 100 times of 100 trys I get no error. if I roll it back to `res = await client.GetStringAsync(url);` I get an error every time.

About the exceptions, again, im getting some indications that the error related to concurrency, this is the save method:

```
public async Task<T> SaveAsync(T entity)
{
    using (var tr = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        //session is injected as scoped
        await session.SaveOrUpdateAsync(entity);
        tr.Commit();
    }
    return entity;
}
```

`MySqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.`

`NHibernate.HibernateException: 'Flush during cascade is dangerous'`

Comment: move the save out of the loop and fyi change `HttpClient client = new HttpClient())` so you are not newing it up everytime. if you want to leave your save in the loop you cant use async also it not gd prac, if you want to leave it  there and keep async then you need a context new for each loop (not recommended!!) like i said save as batchs to the context. SaveChanges, well on ef is by default a transaction on the context, what im suggesting is session injection just sounds like a not great idea.

Comment: @Seabizkit Can you please format your comment and put it in an answer, I really can't understand most of what you wrote. maybe correct my code. thanks for your time.

Comment: @SexyMF HttpClient is thread safe and *meant* to be reused, to reduce the number of sockets used. NHibernate sessions and EF context instances on the other hand are *not* thread-safe. If you get errors from NHibernate, it's probably because the same session is used from multiple threads/requests. In NH only the session factory is thread-safe

Comment: @SexyMF this is by design- sessions are cheap to create, so there's no reason to cache them. They represent roughly a Unit of Work, so nothing gets stored until all changes are stored at the end

Comment: @SexyMF this means that `SaveAsync` breaks NH's design by the way.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you. the reason I use the same session is in the case I have cascade.all, cascading all in a different session is problematic, you end up trying to save/merge 2 different objects from 2 different sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
profile.Data.Locations.ForEach(async x =>
```

The [`ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach) method accepts an `Action`, not an asynchronous delegate. So your `async` delegate does not produce an awaitable `Task`. It produces a `void`. The result is that you end up with an [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) delegate, that has tortured myriads of developers before you (search for [`async void`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=async%20void) to see a never-ending list of related questions). Since the started asynchronous operations are not awaited (they are not awaitable), they are running concurrently. Your database is receiving multiple concurrent requests, and obviously can't handle them well. Not to mention that if any of these operations fail, the error will be thrown on the captured synchronization context, causing most likely the process to crash. You can't handle the error of an `async void` invocation, by wrapping the invocation in a try/catch block.

To solve the problem, just replace the fancy `ForEach` with a plain vanilla `foreach`. Each `Task` will be properly awaited, the unwanted parallelism will not occur, and the problem will be solved.

```
foreach (var x in profile.Data.Locations)
{
    var address = await addressEnrichmentService.EnrichAsync(
        x.StreetAddress + " " + x.Locality + " " + x.Country);
    userModel.Address = address;
    await databaseLogRepository.SaveAsync(new Log{Message = "enriched address"});
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this soon and accept the answer. very glad it is a known issue.

Comment: i do not think this is 100's as i doubt this is the case `Multiple threads are sending concurrent requests to your database, which obviously can't handle parallel requests.`  if it works then cool. all of what you saying is true tho except this quoted line... but i get what you trying to say.

Comment: @Seabizkit apparently when I wrote this answer I was as confused about the `async avoid` methods as the OP was. 